# Buscar item de um objeto dentro de array mongodb

Tags: javascript, array, mongodb, objetos, mongoose

Estou tentando buscar o ID que esta dentro de um objeto dentro de uma array e imprimir na tela, mas ele me retorna o banco de dados inteiro, estou utilizando mongoose

**Codigo:**

```
router.get('/:serverid', Autorizado, async (req, res) => {
    let serverid = req.params.serverid
    console.log( "Id do parametro " + serverid )
    console.log( "Id do servidor: " + await DiscordUser.findOne({ guilds: { id: serverid }}))
}
```

**Database:**

```
_id: new ObjectId("6337bc5f05eb96b00fffea2a"),
  discordId: '939728555376537671',
  __v: 0,
  avatar: 'ce2d2cff2c821ad0fd4d62a9ec723d87',
  discriminator: '0700',
  guilds: [
    {
      id: '310453414511247360',
      name: 'GDD - Grupo de Desenvolvedores',
      icon: 'c7b371e3b9d0a6145d5cdf6fdd16740d',
      owner: false,
      permissions: 104189505,
      features: [Array],
      permissions_new: '831180361281'
    },
    {
      id: '327861810768117763',
      name: 'Rocketseat',
      icon: 'a_86d8605d7ede97bc45a6ad97c7b6d0b5',
      owner: false,
      permissions: 37080641,
      features: [Array],
      permissions_new: '831113252417'
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desculpa, tive multiplas interpretações com a sua pergunta. Alterei a resposta.

Acredito que com o uso do $elemMatch você consegue chegar ao resultado esperado. Porém, você vai precisar percorrer a lista de guilds.

```
router.get('/:serverid', Autorizado, async (req, res) => {
    const serverId = req.params.serverid
    console.log("ID do parâmetro", serverId)
    const discordUserFound = await DiscordUser.findOne({ guilds: { '$elemMatch': { id: serverId } }})

    if (!discordUserFound) {
        return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Server not found!' })
    }

    const guild = discordUserFound.guilds.find(guild => guild.id === serverId)

    console.log("ID do servidor:", guild.id)

    return res.status(200).json({ serverId: guild.id, serverName: guild.name })
})
```

Outra sugestão seria utilizar aggregation. Ficaria assim:

```
router.get('/:serverid', Autorizado, async (req, res) => {
  const serverId = req.params.serverid
  console.log("ID do parâmetro", serverId)
  const guildsFound = await DiscordUser.aggregate([
    {
      '$match': {
        'guilds.id': serverId
      }
    }, {
      '$unwind': '$guilds'
    }, {
      '$match': {
        'guilds.id': serverId
      }
    }, {
      '$project': {
        'guild': '$guilds'
      }
    }
  ])

  if (!guildsFound?.length) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Server not found!' })
  }

  const { guild } = guildsFound[0]

  console.log("ID do servidor:", guild.id)

  return res.status(200).json({ serverId: guild.id, serverName: guild.name })
})
```

Sugiro, se possível, informar o id do usuário (discordId) na busca para fins de otimização.

Mais informações sobre $elemMatch: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/
Mais informações sobre aggregation: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/aggregation/

Comment: Sua resposta me ajudou muito! consegui resolver meu problema, muito obrigado!